# Electrolysis of brine solution gives sodium hydroxide , chlorine and hydrogen gas but catner kellener cell it forms amalgam

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, ph, synthesis

Sodium hydroxide is generally prepared
commercially by the electrolysis of sodium
chloride in Castner-Kellner cell. A brine
solution is electrolyzed using a mercury
cathode and a carbon anode. Sodium metal
discharged at the cathode combines with
mercury to form sodium amalgam.
My question is, why sodium ion discharge on the cathode and why not hydrogen ion?

Comment: Please please explain Why Sodium-ion discharges on cathode instead of hydrogen ion???????

Comment: Discharge potentioal of sodium ion higher than the H+ ion

Comment: True, but there is a lot more Na+ than H+.

Comment: What is the question here? You have made a statement but not a question.

Comment: Na+ ions are discharged in preference to H+ ions due to high over voltage.  see this site:  http://www.citycollegiate.com/sblock3.htm

Comment: Find useful reading about [overpotential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overpotential). the overall effect is combination of this, low activity of H+ and very high activity of Na+ in concentrated NaCl solution.

Comment: When nobody understands a scientific phenomena, we give it a name. Here the name is overpotential. Here the hydrogen is said to have a big "over potential" on mercury cathode. That is a bright and remarkable way to hide our ignorance.

Comment: **MOHIT SINGH GAUR** - Please edit your question to include your first two comments, then delete those comments. We are not use to reading comments to find the basic question.

Comment: 1-On electrolysis of brine (NaCl),  we get dihydrogen gas, Chlorine gas, and NaOH.

Comment: 1-On electrolysis of brine (NaCl),  we get dihydrogen gas, Chlorine gas, and NaOH. But on electrolysis of Brine solution by using carbon anode and mercury cathode, we get chlorine gas at anode and sodium metal at the cathode which makes amalgam.  Why this happen???/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question, rather a collection of words.

Answer (score 4):

I like what Maurice said "*When nobody understands a scientific phenomena, we give it a name. Here the name is overpotential. Here the hydrogen is said to have a big "over potential" on mercury cathode. That is a bright and remarkable way to hide our ignorance*."

This is little on the extreme side but people have spent their life on studying the hydrogen evolution reaction. It is a kinetic issue. It was one of the favorite topics of electrochemists. As one can see in the figure, each electrode evolves hydrogen at a different potential in water. Using mercury in the Castner-Kellner cells, allows sufficient negative voltage that can reduce sodium ions even in the presence of water. Additionally, mercury can form amalgams with many metals. Sodium is not an exception. The moment sodium is reduced at the mercury surface, it is dissolved in the mercury pool, which is periodically tapped off.

Figure taken from: An Electrochemistry Experiment: Hydrogen Evolution Reaction on Different Electrodes in the Journal of Chemical Education.

[image]